# Django blog ProgrammingError/TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am making a Django blog at the moment and I get errors with my code when I try to go in to the superuser admin panel and make a post. When I enter the Python runserver I get error.

I followed along: https://djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django/

**The errors**

> raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html, APP_project4/post_list.html

When I login to superuser and try to click Posts I get error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "APP_project4_post" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "APP_project4_post"

**In the APP folder**

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
        
        
 urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
 path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    
    ]
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)
 
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

**In the project folder:**

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Project_4.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('APP_project4.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url
if os.path.isfile('env.py'):
    import env

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['project4code.herokuapp.com', 'localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'cloudinary',
    'APP_project4',
]

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Project_4.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project_4.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Project_4.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Django Central</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            background-color: #fdfdfd;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .btn-danger {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00000;
            border-color: #dc281e;
        }
        .masthead {
            background: #3398E1;
            height: auto;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Django central</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Content Goes here -->
        {% endblock content %}
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="py-3 bg-grey">
            <p class="m-0 text-dark text-center ">Copyright &copy; Django Central</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }

    .head_text {
        color: white;
    }

    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
    }
</style>

<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h3 class=" site-heading my-4 mt-3 text-white"> Welcome to my awesome Blog </h3>
                    <p class="text-light">We Love Django As much as you do..! &nbsp
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
{% block sidebar %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }

</style>

<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
<div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">About Us</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> This awesome blog is made on the top of our Favourite full stack Framework 'Django', follow up the tutorial to learn how we made it..!</p>
        <a href="https://djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django"
           class="btn btn-danger">Know more!</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Comment: in models.py replace 0 and 1 with "0" and "1".

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` then `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes i ran migrations

Comment: in models.py replace i tried that but dident work that shah said.

Comment: @shahsawood how would that help if status is IntegerField?

Comment: I dident figure it out but made a new repo and it worked from there.